# XSLT - how to output namespace prefix but not namespace definition

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to produce this output which includes a namespace alias but not the definition:

```
<my:Risks>
  <my:Risk>
    <my:ID>1</my:ID> 
    <my:Description><div>test1</div></my:Description>
  </my:Risk>
  <my:Risk>
    <my:ID>2</my:ID> 
    <my:Description><div>test2</div></my:Description>
  </my:Risk>
</my:Risks>
```

from this input:

```
<ArrayOfRisk>
    <Risk>
      <ID>1</ID> 
      <Description><div>test1</div></Description> 
    </Risk>
    <Risk>
      <ID>2</ID> 
      <Description><div>test2</div></Description> 
    </Risk>
</ArrayOfRisk>
```

I am using this XSLT, but need to know how not to have the "my" namespace definition appear in the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:my='http://blaha.com'>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <my:Risks>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Risk"/>
    </my:Risks>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Risk">
    <my:Risk>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </my:Risk>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ID">
    <my:ID><xsl:value-of select="." /></my:ID>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Description">
    <my:Description><xsl:copy-of select="node()" /></my:Description>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Uhm, I very much doubt that XSLT when outputting XML instead of text will allow you to emit invalid XML.

Comment: @Joey That would be possible. But nobody should ever want to do that.

Comment: You could search-and-replace the namespace declaration after XSLT is done. But really, think if you actually need this. Whatever tool requires namespace-lookalike XML but chokes on an actual namespace declaration is broken. Fix that instead of producing broken XML. (Or maybe you can explain why you think you need it in the first place)

Comment: @Tomalak, I can think of a few cases when you *might* want that, though. E.g. if you're assembling a larger document from smaller fragments (via templates instead of an XML writer) and do not want the namespace declaration to be needlessly repeated on every child node. Or if the result has to be readable by some 3rd-party tool that doesn't understand XML, only a bastardization that looks superficially like it (a sadly all too common case in the field where I work – we sometimes have to use certain prefixes because some tools don't parse the declaration, restrict the character set, etc.).

Comment: The resultant XML will be inserted into an existing doc that has the namespace defined already. ! guess the search and replace is my only option :-(.

Answer (score 1):

> The resultant XML will be inserted into an existing doc that has the namespace defined already.

This is not actually a problem as redundant namespace declarations do no harm.

```
<foo:bar xmlns:foo="http://example.com">
  <foo:baz xmlns:foo="http://example.com"/>
</foo:bar>
```

is exactly the same as

```
<foo:bar xmlns:foo="http://example.com">
  <foo:baz />
</foo:bar>
```

as far as any namespace-aware XML parser is concerned. If you want to avoid including the namespace declarations in the first place then you would need to assemble your final document using XML-aware tools rather than simply string concatenation. For example in Java you could build up your XML using something like a StAX [XMLStreamWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html), then when you reach the point where the transformation result should be inserted you pass the open writer to the Transformer (in a [StAXResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stax/StAXResult.html)) and it will write the output in the context of the existing namespace declarations and will know not to add extra redundant ones.

Comment: For some reason the software I am using (Microsoft Infopath) chokes with the error "Schema validation found non-data type errors" when the namespace is present in the inserted xml but works fine when the namespace is not there. Removing the namespace through string replace seems the easiest solution to me just now.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed out XML is invalid:

```
<my:Risks>
  <my:Risk>
    <my:ID>1</my:ID> 
    <my:Description><div>test1</div></my:Description>
  </my:Risk>
  <my:Risk>
    <my:ID>2</my:ID> 
    <my:Description><div>test2</div></my:Description>
  </my:Risk>
</my:Risks>
```

Namespace prefixes must be defined. An XSLT engine will always output valid XML, so will not be able to produce the above.

XML is about data - not cosmetics!

Comment: Technically, the XML is valid but it's not namespace conformant.

Comment: @nwellnhof _technically_ we don't know whether or not it's "valid" without a DTD.  It is _well-formed_ acording to the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) but not _namespace-well-formed_ according to the [Namespaces in XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-nwf).

Answer (score 0):

XSLT cannot produce output that is not namespace-well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess everyone is correct here. For my purposes string manipulation works. But I have learned a bit more about xslt and namespaces. Thanks all.