# Target name space is being printed in the xpath output

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to write an xpath which shows only the tag and the value.

This is the xml file:

```html
<v11:root xmlns:v11="http://example.com">
<v11:Four-Sided>
<v11:SquareName>ABCD</v11:SquareName> 
<v11:RectangleName>EFGH</v11:RectangleName> 
<v11:ParallelName>WXYZ</v11:ParallelName> 
</v11:Four-Sided>
</v11:root>
```

And my xpath is:

```
//v11:SquareName
```

Desired Output:

```
<v11:SquareName>ABCD</v11:SquareName>
```

Actual output:

```
<v11:SquareName xmlns:v11="http://example.com">ABCD</v11:SquareName>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT - how to output namespace prefix but not namespace definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355307/xslt-how-to-output-namespace-prefix-but-not-namespace-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the XPath engine that's serializing the value to lexical XML, it's some other bit of software to which you pass the XPath results. (XPath is used to select nodes, anything that happens to the nodes subsequently is out of XPath's control).

Having said that, most XML serialization libraries, given an element node, will output it as a well-formed XML document containing all required namespace declarations. Without the namespace declaration, how can you know what "v11" means, or do anything useful with it?